# Order of evaluation of print statements in R

Tags: r

I'm unsure about how lazy evaluation of `print` (or `message`, `cat`) functions works.
For example:

```
func1 <- function(i) print("first")
func2 <- function(i) print("second")

1 %>%
  func1() %>%
  func2()
```

```
[1] "second"
```

i.e. only the second print statement executes.

But then, if I perform an operation in each function

```
func3 <- function(i) {
  print("first")
  i + 1
}

func4 <- function(i) {
  print("second")
  i * 2
}

1 %>%
  func3() %>%
  func4()
```

```
[1] "second"
[1] "first"
[1] 4
```

then the `print` statements come out backwards, but the operations on `i` occur in the correct order (`(1+1)*2=4`).

If I incorporate the `i` into the print statement, everything comes out in order:

```
func5 <- function(i) {
  print(paste("first", i))
  i + 1
}

func6 <- function(i) {
  print(paste("second", i))
  i * 2
}

1 %>%
  func5() %>%
  func6()
```

```
[1] "first 1"
[1] "second 2"
[1] 4
```

What's going on here? How do I force the print statements to execute in the correct order? Reading about lazy evaluation, I found people using the `force` function, but wrapping the `print` statements in that doesn't seem to change anything.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The code in the first block prints both `[1] "first"` and `[1] "second"`. The second code block prints `[1] "first"` `[1] "second"` and `[1] 4`. What library are you using `%>%` from?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results either. Where are you running this code? Are you using the R GUI? Or RStudio? Are you looking at the output in the console? The behavior of print as far as evaluation goes should be no different than `cat()`.

Comment: Hmmm...For me (like OP) `1 %>% func1() %>% func2()` returns only `[1] "second"`.  I am on R 4.0.3

Comment: @Ian @ MrFlick Thanks so much for your help.
I have access to two environments in which I've been able to replicate this, both in the console and from sourcing a script:                   
1) RStudio for Windows 1.3.1093, R for Windows 4.0.3, with either magrittr_2.0.1 or dplyr_1.0.2                   
2) RStudio Server for Ubuntu 1.4.1103, Microsoft R Open 4.0.2, with either magrittr_2.0.1 or dplyr_1.0.4                   
I've found it's also replicable using the browser-based R snippets website: https://rdrr.io/snippets/

Comment: I've done some additional testing with the rocker Docker images. In the `rocker/tidyverse:4.0.5` environment, the issue is as I have described, but in the `rocker/tidyverse:3.6.3` environment, I see no issue, like @IanCampbell